# How to stop panic?

Tags: anxiety-disorders, psychologist-psychology, healthy-cooking, panic-attack

I feel fear when I should talk to a girl or do my exams or do things I am obliged to do. It happens in the morning, I wake up with fear and I can't handle the situation. My thoughts are negative and I can't do anything to change it.

I have talked to two doctors; one's solution was to take pills and the other to do a physical program and a healthy diet that will do my body better. I find both solutions wrong.

For the first, I think I will depend on the pills and when I face a more difficult situation, I will need more a powerful pill. I could harm myself with those, right? For the second, maybe I'll be healthier but I believe a healthy diet will not improve the situation of this panic.

What can I do now? I am disappointed.

Answer (score 4):

In general, anxiety can be handled with medications or with "talking therapy", of which there are many types. So far you have seen two doctors.

One offered medication. You were concerned about depending on them rather than learning to handle situations yourself, and about possible side effects or damage to yourself from those pills. These are wonderful things to discuss with that doctor. You can ask about side effects, you can ask if the doctor thinks you need to be on the medications indefinitely or just while you learn to handle difficult situations, and so on. You can also ask about needing higher doses for more difficult situations. Once you thoroughly understand what the doctor is suggesting and why, and the benefits and risks of it, you can decide whether you want to take it and how you will know whether you want to keep taking it or not.

One recommended just getting healthier overall. A great question to ask that doctor is why that might help? Perhaps you're sleeping very poorly. Perhaps some blood tests have shown you are suffering from deficiencies that might cause anxiety. You need a reason to believe that exercise and healthy food will help the anxiety, right? That said, living a healthy live often means living a happy life with less worry, so if you can afford (time and money) to walk more, spend time outside, eat fresh food you cooked yourself, and take up an active hobby, I would encourage you to do that as a good thing in itself that might happen to lower your panic situation too.

In addition to asking more questions from the two doctors you've already spoken to, you can look into counseling or therapy. There are many kinds! [CBT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_behavioral_therapy) is often suggested for anxiety - rather than discussing your childhood and trying to find out why you react as you do, it focuses on teaching you specific skills for coping with things that distress you today. Many people learn what they need to learn from such counselling and then stop doing it. The Wikipedia article includes links to studies, including one specifically about adults with anxiety.

Answer (score 1):

If a doctor mentioned eating a healthier diet in relation to your problems then that suggests that your diet is pretty bad. We can't judge if that's the case, but if you are not eating well, e.g. lack of proteins in your diet, not enough calories etc., then that will affect your psychological well being. Your brain will hit the stress and anxiety button a lot sooner if your energy levels are low due to chronic malnutrition.